# How to join a table to itself in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table (“ProductParameter”) that links two tables together (“Product” and “Parameter”) it has the fields Id, ProductId, ParameterId, Value, each ParameterId has a set [Value] I need to filter the collection first by two ParameterId (where pp.ParameterId = 4 or pp1.ParameterId = 2 and pp1.Value = 'Standard') after filtering one by one ParameterId (where pp.ParameterId = 4).

Example:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+---------+
|     ID  |  ProductId  |ParameterId | Value   | 
+---------+-------------+------------+---------+
|     25  |    14       |    2       | Standard|
|     26  |    14       |    3       |  CK45   |
|     27  |    14       |    4       |   63    |
|     28  |    15       |    2       |   XXX   |
|     29  |    15       |    3       |  CK45   |
|     30  |    15       |    4       |   70    |
|     34  |    17       |    2       | Standard|
|     35  |    17       |    3       |  CK45   |
|     36  |    17       |    4       |   40    |
|     37  |    25       |    2       | Standard|
|     38  |    25       |    3       |  CK45   |
|     39  |    25       |    4       |   20    |     
+---------+-------------+------------+---------+-
```

should return:

```
+-------+
| Value |  
+-------+
|   63  |   
|   40  | 
|   20  | 
+-------+
```

The logic of the query is as follows:

```
 select distinct pp.Value from ProductParameters pp
 join ProductParameters pp1 on pp1.ProductId = pp.ProductId and 
 pp1.ParameterId = 2 and pp1.Value = 'Standard'
 where pp.ParameterId = 4
```

Here is my query in the EF core:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductParameter>> GetProductDiameters(long id, string param = "Standard")
{
    var value = await _context.ProductParameters
        .Include(p => p.Product)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductParameters.Where(i => i.Value == param))
        .Where(p => p.ParameterId == id)
        .Distinct()
        .ToListAsync();

    return value;
}
```

Throws exception:

> ArgumentException: The ThenInclude property lambda expression 'p => {from ProductParameter i in p.ProductParameters where ([i].Value == __param_0) select [i]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductParameters.Where(i => i.Value == param)) should be .ThenInclude(p=>p.ProductParameters).Where(i=>i.Product.ProductParameters.Value == param)

Comment: than Where(i=>i.Product.ProductParameters does not contain Value

Comment: right, it is a collection. Then the correct syntax (instead of .Where(..)) would be .ForEach(i=>i.Product.ProductParameters=i.Product.ProductParameters.Where(p=>p.Value==param))

Answer (score 0):

EF complains because you are trying to **filter** inside the .`ThenInclude(..)` statement.

```
var value = await _context.ProductParameters
    .Include(p => p.Product)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductParameters.Where(i => i.Value == param)) //<-- here
    .Where(p => p.ParameterId == id)
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is a problem, because EF will use the function inside the to determine *what tables that should be eager loaded*. These functions inside `Include(..)` and `ThenInclude(..)` should **always** point to a related table, and **nothing else** :)

The correct way of doing your query is like this:

```
var value = await _context.ProductParameters
    .Include(p => p.Product)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductParameters) // <- removed the Where clause from here
    .Where(p => p.ParameterId == id)
    .Where(p => p.ProductParameters.Value == param)) //<- and added it here
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```